# Cordova/appFramework app shows up blank on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3, hybrid-mobile-app, appframework

I've a very simple hybrid mobile application developed with Cordova and appFramework.

index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and
    height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org
    /jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,
    maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, 
    height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/main.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/appframework.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/lists.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/forms.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/buttons.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/badges.css"  />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/grid.css"  />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/android.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/win8.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/bb.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/ios.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/ios7.css"  />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af/tizen.css"  />

    <title>Cordova Application</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="js/vendor/appframework.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/plugins/af.scroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/plugins/af.css3animate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/ui/appframework.ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/ui/transitions/fade.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/ui/transitions/flip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/ui/transitions/pop.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/ui/transitions/slide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/ui/transitions/slideDown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/ui/transitions/slideUp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
    src="js/vendor/plugins/af.slidemenu.js"></script>

    <script>
        $.ui.ready(function () {
            console.log("UI Ready!!!");
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('Document Ready...');
            alert('Document Ready...');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="afui">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div data-title="Home" class="panel"
                                 id="main" selected="true">
                <span>THIS is the HOME Page!</span>
            </div>
            <div data-title="Second Page" class="panel" id="second">
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="title">Nav Home</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="icon home mini"
                                    href="#main">Home Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="icon mini"
                                    href="#second">Second Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This shows up correctly and even the navigation is wired up when opened in Safari or Chrome desktop browsers.

But if I run it in either iOS or Android emulators, I see the alert 'Document Ready' and after that blank page. Home panel is not displayed.

Here is what I do to run the emulators.

```
 cordova emulate ios
 cordova emulate android
```

Even if I open the index.html files directly from the platform builds they show up correctly on the desktop browser.

I'm pretty new to all this so I may be missing steps here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need all the fragmented appframework js and css files, you can just include 2 css and 1 js file, here is updated code, it works as cordova app on android, I built Cordova app with **[Intel XDK](http://xdk.intel.com)**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XDK</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/af.ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icons.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/appframework.ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $.ui.ready(function () {
            console.log("UI Ready!!!");
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('Document Ready...');
            alert('Document Ready...');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="afui">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div title="Home" class="panel" id="main" selected="true">
                <span>THIS is the HOME Page!</span>
            </div>
            <div title="Second Page" class="panel" id="second">
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="title">Nav Home</div>
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a class="icon home mini" href="#main">Home Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="icon mini" href="#second">Second Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you effort, Since I don't see a difference between your HTML and mine, except for removing some excess CSS references, should I take it as it's the XDK build which made it work in your case? So perhaps Cordova build is missing something in my case?

Comment: i have not used cordova cli much, there are some configuration you have to do and setup config.xml to get the build right. IntelXDK makes that easy. Your code is correct, something with build settings

Comment: I used XDK to create a project and compared the difference, I think the issue was with the way I included appframework.*.js files, XDK includes the appframework.ui.min.js, if I include that (and the css files), then things are good. Problem is, I can't find the min file to be downloaded, except from the CDN, and the downloaded package does not contain instructions on how to build it. While XDK is a good tool, I don't like if appFramework only works when projects are built using that.

Comment: XDK does not include an appframework files, appframework should work independently, if not there is a bug, i will check

Comment: Thanks @krisrak, I was wrong to say appframework.ui.min.js was not in the download. It is there in the build folder. So it's correct that it will work without the XDK. Thanks again for the effort.